# Looking for the original Japanese of this haiku

Tags: translation, resources, quotes, poetry

I'm sure this is a translation of a haiku but I'm not able to find the original text or even the author.

> As the sun
>
> goes down the birds
>
> land one by one.

I've been trying to Google it but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, without more context, there is no reason to believe this is related to the Japanese language.

Comment: @JudoWill : what is kanji of haiku?That is はいく【俳句】?

「俳句」a haiku means  a Japanese poem of seventeen syllables ［in 5‐7‐5 syllabic form］